# Incomplete list of modules with python help('modules')

Tags: python, pip

I'm working with python 3.8 on a linux machine which has no internet access and on which I'm not allowed to install anything. Installation of tools (even python modules) is done by admins.

I'm able to import some freshly installed modules like crcmod or pycryptomod in my own python code.

I see these modules when I do `pip list`

But I don't see them when I do `help('modules')`.

Any reason for that ? I suspect the installation of the new modules by the admin was perhaps not orthodox.

Comment: But you can import the modules without problem? And can you use the functionality of those modules?

Comment: Actually I can call the modules methods but it looks like there are dependencies issues

Comment: I'm asking the question because after the admin guy told me he had installed the modules, I did a quick `help('modules')` and it didn't show the new modules so I was confused

Comment: Sounds like you need to figure out what the dependency issues are, and then ask the admins to install those, if the dependencies are missing.

Comment: @9769953 yes of course, but my question was more on the inconsistency between the two methods to get the list of installed modules. Unless this "inconsistency" is due to missing dependencies ?

Comment: Are there any specific error messages regarding these modules when running `help('modules')`?

Comment: From what I can see, `help('modules')` recursively goes through all modules *and* their submodules. That could include such unfound dependencies, and as a result may not show the actual module(s). `import <module>` doesn't do that: it basically just imports the namespace, and only when you access or execute something in that namespace, things might break. So `help('modules')` does provide some sort of consistency check that you wouldn't immediately notice with just `import <module>`.

Comment: I'm not sure what `pip list` exactly does, but presumably it just scans quickly through packages found on `sys.path` (and perhaps just the `-info` files), instead of going through submodules.